# Is there way to find the pharse and capture next token value

Tags: python, parsing

So I have a file of this on the server:

COADREAD    ATF7    Missense_Mutation   NGXA-AZ-3984    P17544  A436T

COADREAD    ATG10   Missense_Mutation   NGXA-AB-A010    Q9H0Y0  H133N

my goal is find the id (P17544), which in column 5 of the file and capture/store(which i need to print that number later) the number of the token behind it which is 436(this number is suppose to be in between two letter) from A436T in column 6.
Is there way that I can do this? I worked a little bit with  lxml before but still not sure how to do this. thanks in advance

Here is what I have

file = open('text.txt','r')

lookup={}

for line in file:

```
myid, token = file.rsplit(' ', 2)[1:]

token = token[1:-1]
```

Comment: What is the name of this type of encoding?

Comment: @K.Brafford just plain text file

Comment: @TankorSmash Yes something like that there are buch of token in the file.. Basically i need to first find the id and find the value from the token behind the id i found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest method *using builtin `str` methods*:

```
d = 'COADREAD ATF7 Missense_Mutation NGXA-AZ-3984 P17544 A436T'
myid, token = d.rsplit(' ', 2)[1:] # will except if can't be unpacked so you know you've got exactly 2 elements...
token = token[1:-1]
```

You could use regular expressions though if you wanted to specify numbers between two letters... `re.match('[A-Z](\d{3})[A-Z]', token[1]) # or similar...`

**Clarification:**

`d.rsplit(' ', 2)` - starts splitting the string at `' '`s from the end which returns `['COADREAD ATF7 Missense_Mutation NGXA-AZ-3984', 'P17544', 'A436T']`
. Assuming we're only looking for the last 2 elements, we remove the first one with a slice, so we get `d.rsplit(' ', 2)[1:]` which gives `['P17544', 'A436T']`.

Using unpacking, we name our variables and also guarantee it has a length of two by using `myid, token = d.rsplit(' ', 2)[1:]` - if it didn't have exactly two elements, the assignment will fail.

Now that `myid` should be your id that you want you remove the first and last character from token using slicing which is `token = token[1:-1]`.

Then:

```
print myid, token
# P17544 436
```

**Comment about looking up:**

For looking up after parsing the lines of the file:

```
lookup = {}
for line in file:
    # do steps above so you have myid, token
    lookup[myid] = token
```

Then lookup['P17544'] will return '436'

Hope that's clearer...

Comment: could you please tell me what are you doing when you have [1:] after d.rsplit and token = token[1:-1]. and i don't really get about regular expression at all thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not sure about standard string methods, then maybe best to leave regular expressions unless they're absolutely required. I've tried to clarify this answer though.

Comment: @JonClemensts this is clear but I am not sure about how would it know to look for certain ids for example P17544 or Q9H0Y0?

Comment: @ChadD How do you mean "look for"?

Comment: my goal is i need to find the line with id that i want and capture the value of the token behind that id. but how do i find that id in the first place

Comment: I am confuse..could you please tell me if i have is correct? I will post that above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13760/discussion-between-chad-d-and-jon-clements)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds quite easy ... split along the spaces - then extract fifth field ... and all digit from the sixth field. Or am I missing something?

```
>>> tokens = "COADREAD ATF7 Missense_Mutation NGXA-AZ-3984 P17544 A436T".split()
>>> print tokens[4]
P17544
>>> print ''.join([c for c in tokens[5] if c.isdigit()])
436
```

Comment: in the file there is multiple lines of similar text i post, would this always work... i basically have to find the id and then look at the token behind it for the number between two letters.

Comment: @ChadD Is the id always in the 5th column? If so, then it this should work for all lines. If not, how do you know what the ID is?

Comment: yes id is always the fifth column. but i am not sure if ''.join([c for c in tokens[5] if c.isdigit()]) gives me the number from the line with the correct id

Comment: @ChadD That bit just pulls out all the digits from 6th column ... isn't that what's required?