# parsing line capture value in the ttoken

Tags: python, parsing

My goal is to find the line that has id on the plain text file then get the value of the token behind that id. On my file has 100s of lines similar to this: (the 5th column is always the id that i search for and the 6th column is the token i need to grab/store the number between two alphabet.

For example if I am looking for id Q9C0F0, i want to get/store value 1136( which is between 2 alphabet-K and N). Then i want to use that number to print on the outputfile. Thanks in advance

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AA-3672    Q9C0F0  K1136N

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AA-3693    Q9C0F0  A1544E

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AA-A010    Q9C0F0  F353S

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AA-A010    Q9C0F0  L157I

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AG-3890    Q9C0F0  L1324Q

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AG-A002    Q9C0F0  H552N

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   KFGM-AG-A002    Q9C0F0  K471N

COAAD   ASXL3   Missense_Mutation   TKFGM-AG-A002   Q9C0F0  L804M

Comment: You mention only one match but we can see 8 lines containing Q9C0F0. Do you want only the first match?

Comment: Reference previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441161/is-there-way-to-find-the-pharse-and-capture-next-token-value/11441288#comment15097820_11441288

Comment: @badzil i want all the math. would it be possible? because i need to use those number and see if it in the domain range and print it out to the file that has correct domain range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way how to do it, maybe it will help you, corectness of the "algorithm" depends on the input condition, so maybe you will need to change parsing of the integers and change some conditions

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        l = line.split()
        if l and l[4] == 'Q9C0F0':
            print l[5][1:-1] # or parse int in a more inteligent way
```

Comment: this work really wells. is there a way to return/store values.. what i try to do here is i want to use those value to calculate and see test whether if it in the range that i want.

Comment: You can store your values in a list and then process the list.